# How to push in Firebase-Dart?

Tags: dart, firebase

I am experimenting with the latest version of **Firebase-Dart (0.5.0)** and was trying to replicate the JavaScript Firebase Chat tutorial (https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/chat) using the Dart library.

I am trying to use the `push` function of the library as follows:

```dart
f = new Firebase('https://uniqueID.firebaseio-demo.com/');
f.push(value: {
               'name': 'John',
               'text': 'hello again'
});
```

But the data is not stored. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you check if it's stored? I haven't used Firebase myself yet so this might be a stupid question but if you check it with code following the above code then the value might have been *not yet* stored. `push` is an async operation and you need to wait until it's finished. `push` returns a future and you can register a callback to be called when `push` is done.
`f.push(...).then((v) { code that depends on push being finished });`

Comment: Firebase allows you to log in and use the provided URL to see the data getting updated in realtime. So, even if it is an async operation, you know it is not getting changed.

Comment: I see. Then I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the test file in the firebase dart wrapper git repo I found this:

```dart
test('push', () {
  // TODO: actually validate the result
  var pushRef = f.push();
  return pushRef.set('HAHA');
});
```

So in summary, I think you need to do the push, then set it's value:

```dart
f = new Firebase('https://uniqueID.firebaseio-demo.com/');
var pushRef = f.push();
pushRef.set("{'name': 'John','text': 'hello again'}");
```

Please see the firebase package test script here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart/blob/master/test/test.dart

Comment: Voila! It worked. I had seen the git dart wrapper file too but somehow I missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For latest version(v0.6.3) of [dart version firebase](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase) library I am using now , it's very straightforward to use **push** to push (and use Future to move on to next action)

```
firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://uniqueID.firebaseio-demo.com/');
firebaseRef.push(value: {"hi": "dart"}, onComplete: (err) {
  print("err = ${err}");
});
```